# How to default search to organization to see promoted search?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, promoted-results

I am working to use promoted search results to help guide our users towards their most common query faster. The issue is that you have to select Organization in order to see promoted search results. Does anyone have any recommendations for solving the issue of displaying promoted search results in the default search or making the default search the organization search?

FYI - This is for SharePoint Online

Search example for a promoted result I added:

[image]

It does not display the promoted result, clicking Organization
[image]
Now it shows the promoted search result

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

did not come across this. But logical thinking tells me to do below

1. Get the Organizational results page URL (it would differ from normal search with respect to parameters I suppose)
2. Set it as the default search results page

> Below is not a desired way

If above cannot be accomplished (meaning the URL doesn't change between normal search and org search & its an internal PostBack), then see whats happening while you click on "org" using F12 dev tools and try to call that on page load (Jquery.load(executeOrgClick))

Comment: Looking at the setting it is currently set to be:
https://domain.sharepoint.com/search/Pages

When searching this is what comes up:
https://domain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/search.aspx/siteall?q=ACT
When selecting organization:
https://domain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/search.aspx?q=ACT

I'm not sure what I would be adjusting it to be.

Comment: you see that /siteall being an extra text in the normal search. Where is this being configured. Remove that & you should by default see the org results. Check site collection level search settings

Answer (score 0):

came across this question when I was searching for a solution myself. You can use PnP powershell to make Organization level search as default.

Refer:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/configure-modern-search-results-to-search-all-of-your/m-p/447334